# checkbox internal state overriding prop

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

I'm surprised that the checkbox functionality is not what I expect to happen. If I have a wrapper div with an `onClick`, and click on anything except the checkbox, it works as expected. However when I click on the checkbox, even though the propp passed down did update, the checkbox stays in the same state. My guess is that the checkbox is firing its internal update event after the prop change get pushed down.

```
const ToDo = (props) => {
  const { title, done, onChange } = props;

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (onChange) {
      onChange(!done)
    }
  }

  return (
    <div onClick={handleChange}>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" checked={done}/> {title}
      </label>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I'm wondering what is the correct way of dealing with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What seems to be happening is that when you click on the label, it's calling the checkbox's `onChange` function and also the div's `onClick`.

One easy way around this is to disable pointer-events on the label, so only the `onClick` is called (I assume there is some reason you need an `onClick` on the parent instead of `onChange` on the input itself).

There is probably another way to stop the event from propagating up, but then you have to deal with multiple handlers, so the css way seems like an easy fix.

Here's a demo:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    done: false
  }
  
  onCheckDone = (done) => {
    this.setState({
      done
    });
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <ToDo
        title="hello"
        done={this.state.done}
        onChange={this.onCheckDone}
      />
    );
  }
}

const ToDo = (props) => {
  const { title, done, onChange } = props;

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    if (onChange) {
      onChange(!done)
    }
  }
  
  return (
    <div className="clicker" onClick={handleChange}>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" checked={done} /> {title}
      </label>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```css
.clicker {
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

label {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the work-around I've found to be easy and works. Passing a different key `key={done}` will force the re-render of the checkbox component as a different dom item, so it works, but it seems like there should be a better way to do this. I know that this is not needed when using a text input, as the value remains whatever the prop passes down.

```
const ToDo = (props) => {
  const { title, done, onChange } = props;

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (onChange) {
      onChange(!done)
    }
  }

  return (
    <div onClick={handleChange}>
      <label>
        <input key={done} type="checkbox" checked={done}/> {title}
      </label>
    </div>
  );
};
```